# C# changing the background image of multiple controls

Tags: c#, winforms

In C# forms I've created a function that will, once invoked, create a picturebox with desired image, size and location:

```
private void NewPic(string nName, int locX, int locY, int SizX, int SizY, Image Img)
{
    PictureBox Pic = new PictureBox();
    Pic.Name = nName; Pic.Image = Img;
    Pic.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
    Pic.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
    Pic.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(SizX, SizY);
    Pic.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(locX, locY);
    Controls.Add(Pic);
    Pic.Click += new EventHandler(Pic_Click);
}
```

Now when I need a picture I just do this:

```
NewPic("FIRE", 32, 100, 120, 120, Properties.Resources.Image);
```

The problem is, in the click event, when I click on picturebox I want it to change its background image, but, if I click some other picturebox I want the last one to reset it self:

```
private void Pic_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    PictureBox pb = (PictureBox)sender;
    switch (pb.Name)
    {
        case "1": 
            pb.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.OtherImg; //creates the background
            pb.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
                //INSERT CODE HERE: to remove from other if it has
            break;
        case "2":
            pb.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.OtherImg; //creates the background
            pb.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
                //INSERT CODE HERE: to remove from other if it has
            break;
        }
     }
```

I need code that can be applied to multiple pictureboxes/objects, not just the two

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to store the image of last picture box too

```
PictureBox _lastPictureBox = null;
Image _lastPictureBoxImage = null;

private void Pic_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    PictureBox pb = (PictureBox)sender;
    if (_lastPictureBox != null) 
    {
      // update the previous one, eg:
       _lastPictureBox.BackgroundImage = _lastPictureBoxImage;
    }

    // now set it to the current one:
   _lastPictureBox = pb;
   _lastPictureBoxImage = pb.Image;
   switch (pb.Name)
   {
     case "1": 
       pb.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.OtherImg; //creates the background
       pb.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
    break;
    case "2":
      pb.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.OtherImg; //creates the background
      pb.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
    break;
  }
```

}

Comment: Y>es, this is what I was missing, thank you, and thanks everyone. If you have more suggestions I will consider them all :)

Comment: The "switch statement" also seems to be repetitive and can be eliminated in case there is a same background image for every picture box.

Comment: In either case of switch statement the same following code is executed.

pb.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.OtherImg; 
pb.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to add a member to your form, that will track the previously-clicked PictureBox:

```
PictureBox _lastPictureBox = null;
```

In the handler, check if _lastPictureBox has a value, and update it as needed:

```
private void Pic_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    PictureBox pb = (PictureBox)sender;
    if (_lastPictureBox != null) 
    {
        // update the previous one, eg:
        _lastPictureBox.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.FirstImg;
    }

    // now set it to the current one:
    _lastPictureBox = pb;

    switch (pb.Name)
    {
    case "1": 
        pb.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.OtherImg; //creates the background
        pb.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
        break;
    case "2":
        pb.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.OtherImg; //creates the background
        pb.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
        break;
    }
 }
```

Comment: hmmm, I think this is not working. problem is I have 4 created pictureboxes, so they are not empty, so when _lastpicturebox = null nothing will happen since I have no empty pictureboxes

Comment: @AntonioTehSumtin _lastPictureBox is null at first, so it does nothing.  But the first time the user clicks on a picture, _lastPictureBox gets a reference to that picture (so you can reset it on the next click).

Answer (score 0):

if I understand you correctly, you need a global variable

```
PictureBox lastbox;
```

then you can insert this code:

```
lastbox.Image = Properties.Resources.Image;
lasbox = pb;
```

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't really think you helped too much ^^' thank you for trying tho much appreciated. :)